# Firebase Firestore - Bandwidth Costs

Tags: ios, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I noticed when looking at my usage and billing today in Firebase Firestore that I have incurred some fees. I am a bit confused as to where this is coming from. I've only once exceeded the daily free limits of Reads/Writes and it was by only a few hundred operations. It appears all the cost is from "Bandwidth". Is anyone able to explain to me where this "Bandwidth" is from, and why, when my reads/writes are very low, less than 1k daily, that the bandwidth charge seems to remain. I've attached a screenshot for reference as to what I am seeing. Any insight on this matter would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

[image]

See below a sample JSON of the session-details object.

Note: Every time a user swipes on an item, it is added to the `swiped_titles` array, so you can imagine this becoming quite a large array:

```html
{
  "id" : 1202193,
  "hostUid" : "kasdnjadkjlnaASD",
  "uids": [
    "kasdnjadkjlnaASD",
    "nasduhASafafafdf"
  ],
  "created": "{TIMESTAMP HERE}",
  "last_updated": "{TIMESTAMP HERE}",
  "swiped_titles": [
      {
        "id": 09234,
        "backdropPath": "URL_HERE",
        "posterPath": "URL_HERE",
        "tilte": "Dim Sum Koi",
        "overview": "The best dim sum in the city. Authentic, delicious. made to order.",
        "category": "dine-in",
        "voteAverage": 7.3,
        "voteCount": 219,
        "uids-that-liked": [
          "kasdnjadkjlnaASD",
          "nasduhASafafafdf"
          ],
        "uids-that-swiped": [
          "kasdnjadkjlnaASD",
          "nasduhASafafafdf"
          ]
      },
      {
        "id": 08123,
        "backdropPath": "URL_HERE",
        "posterPath": "URL_HERE",
        "tilte": "That's Italian Ristorante",
        "overview": "The best fine dining italian experience in town. Delicious, family-style.",
        "category": "dine-in",
        "voteAverage": 8.3,
        "voteCount": 180,
        "uids-that-liked": [
          "nasduhASafafafdf"
          ],
        "uids-that-swiped": [
          "kasdnjadkjlnaASD",
          "nasduhASafafafdf"
          ]
      }
    ]
  }
```

Comment: How big are these documents?

Comment: @MJ-12 - i think that is in fact that underlying issue. The documents grow to be quite big over time. I'm not sure exact size of documents but yes they definitely grow to be quite large

Comment: Were you able to solve this problem? I have also had an issue with bandwidth costs that seem to just be rising every single day despite my read/write and functions operations staying exactly the same, you can see my question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76318265/firebase-bandwidth-costs-rising-exponentially-month-over-month-despite-no-change

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned by @Frank, Firestore also charges for bandwidth along with reads. The pricing is described in detailed [here](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/pricing).

> When you use Firestore, you are charged for the following:
>
> The number of documents you read, write, and delete. The amount of
> storage that your database uses, including overhead for metadata and
> indexes. The amount of network bandwidth that you use. Storage and
> bandwidth usage are calculated in gigabytes (GiB), where 1 GiB = 2<sup>30</sup>
> bytes. All charges accrue daily.

Internet Egress pricing can be found in detail [here](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/pricing#internet-egress).

The `$0.04` charge on reads suggests you have around 60K reads over the free quota so if your documents are fairly large, let's say 650 KB then that roughly estimates around 39 GB of bandwidth (out of which 10 GB is free). That still totals around not more than 4 USD. If your docs are even large then that may be possible. If not, you should head for Firebase support.

Comment: I believe the underlying issue is the size of my documents. I'm unsure how to best handle this. The nature of the application is a "session" document that multiple users can read and write to. Think Tinder swipe application but for restaurants within your area. Each time a user swipes on a restaurant some of its data is added to a nested array in the document

Comment: @MikeSimz can you share how your document looks like? Maybe you can fetch its once, log/print it and share a sample JSON object?

Comment: Will do - give me a few

Comment: updated the question to include a sample JSON object. Notice the `swiped_titles` array. This is what grows very large as users swipe on items

Comment: @MikeSimz the properties "uids-that-liked" and "uids-that-swiped" could be extremely large arrays. The swiped-titles itself could be a large array. I usually maintain a subcollection for such things. I can't guess exact amount of data but you can do this sub collections workaround (Firestore has 1 MB per doc limit so you would have to do that anyways). If the answer was help, you can accept/upvote it so others know it's helpful.

Comment: Using subcollections, how would i be able to determine matches? When User A swipes YES on a title, if User B has already swiped YES on it, the users should be notified of a match

Comment: @MikeSimz I don't have a perfect idea of how this app works, but if you would like to keep the public i.e. visible to all users, then you can actually create a dedicated collection for that. In fact, I had the same document size issue while working on a blog like website, storing UIDs of users who have marked a blog as favorite was difficult due to 1 MB limit of Firestore doc. I have a separate collection for favorites and each doc represents a favorite containing userID, blogID and the timestamp.

Comment: The "uids-that-liked" and "uids-that-swiped" arrays will never grow larger than the total users in the swipe session (which has a max of 4). That being said, what will grow extremely large is the "swiped-titles" array itself, as the 2-4 users continue to swipe on titles from their respective devices

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233061/discussion-between-dharmaraj-and-mike-simz).

Answer (score 0):

Firestore charges both for read *operations*, as well as for the bandwidth consumed by those operations. So any time an SDK (or the console) reads a document from the server, you're charged for the read operation and the bytes sent over the wire.

Apparently in your case the bandwidth consumed was the majority of the cost. That is not the usual case with Firestore, but it's definitely possible, for example: if your documents are all quite large.

If you think this is not the case, [reach out to Firebase support](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/troubleshooting/) for personalized help in troubleshooting. They can check your project for more information, something nobody else here can do.

Comment: I believe the underlying issue is the size of my documents. I'm unsure how to best handle this. The nature of the application is a "session" document that multiple users can read and write to. Think Tinder swipe application but for restaurants within your area. Each time a user swipes on a restaurant some of its data is added to a nested array in the document

Comment: If your documents are sufficient large that could explain why you pay more for bandwidth. If you're concerned about this, you could consider storing some of the repated data of the documents into a subcollection, but that might mean you then start paying for more document reads. In the end, you need to make your own judgment call on what the best model is, given your own trade-offs.