# Firebase bandwidth costs rising exponentially month over month despite no changes and few users

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I started using firebase for the first time in early april for a project, I was attracted to the idea of using it because of it's relatively simple user interface to setup and reasonable read/write/functions fees and healthy free tier, at the end of the first month I received an unexpected bill which was odd considering my app only has a few paid users who have access to database and I was well beneath the paid levels, I realized this was a bandwidth cost, at the time it was unexpected but was still fairly a small cost so I paid it and thought nothing of it, today I logged into the console to check on what my bandwidth cost will be for the current month and to my shock the cost of bandwidth has increased 3x and is forecast to be at 4x by month end, nothing has changed and at this rate I will not be able to afford the fees even with paid users within a few months, I have a scheduled function that makes 10 web service calls every 4 minutes and writes that data to the firestore database, I will post some photos below showing my monthly usage stats which considering that nothing has changed from last month to this month I do not understand how this makes sense.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Is this normal? I would expect that if nothing changed the bandwidth cost would at the very least stayed the same however everyday it just goes up higher, if this is not normal and if anyone else has experienced this can someone explain to me how to fix it?

Comment: Most likely is something related to your code. It will be helpful to see the code that generates so many reads.

Comment: @AlexMamo am I not well beneath the free reads tier? This is what I find confusing because I'm well beneath the free reads tier, the free writes tier and well beneath the functions invocations tier as well yet the bandwidth cost is rising exponentially every day, at this rate I've worked out within a few months I'll easily be spending hundreds a months even if nothing changes

Comment: What's the code you're using?

Comment: @EdmundRojas Are your Cloud Functions and Firestore locations close to each other? See https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/locations